# How to import a module as __main__?

Tags: python

I have a module that has the usual

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    do stuff...
```

idiom.

I'd like to import that from another module, and fool it into running that code.  Is there any way of doing this?

I should mention, for reasons I won't go into here, I'm not in a position to change the code in the imported module. I need to somehow modify the import procedure so that it's name is main when imported, perhaps using ihooks or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer has been already given however it is confined in a comments (see [How to import a module as __main__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160643/how-to-import-a-module-as-main#comment86906440_31395912)
and [How to import a module as __main__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160643/how-to-import-a-module-as-main#comment103989404_31395912)).

The same with proper formatting:

```
import runpy
runpy.run_module("your.module.name", {}, "__main__")
```

or

```
import runpy
runpy.run_path("path/to/my/file.py", {}, "__main__")
```

Answer (score 19):

As pointed out in the other answers, this is a bad idea, and you should solve the issue some other way.

Regardless, the way Python does it is like this:

```
import runpy
result = runpy._run_module_as_main("your.module.name"))
```

Comment: This works, but since the module being run will share the same global namespace as your current code, it might read and/or overwrite values that you would prefer it not read/overwrite. You could call `runpy.run_module("your.module.name", {}, "__main__")` instead, which will give it an independent global namespace.

Comment: And for filenames instead of dotted import names, use `runpy.run_path("path/to/my/file.py", {}, "__main__")`.

Answer (score 8):

There is, execute the script instead of importing it. But I consider this an extremely hackish solution.

However the ideal pattern would be:

```
def do_stuff():
    ... stuff happens ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_stuff()
```

that way you can do:

```
from mymodule import do_stuff
do_stuff()
```

**EDIT**: Answer after clarification on not being able to edit the module code.

**I would never recommend this in any production code, this is a "use at own risk" solution.**

```
import mymodule

with open(os.path.splitext(mymodule.__file__)[0] + ".py") as fh:
    exec fh.read()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've clarified the question - I can't modify the imported module to have all the code in a do_stuff function like that.

Answer (score 3):

Put that code in a function, and call it from the module you are importing it into as well.

```
def stuff():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    stuff()
```

And then in the module you are importing it into:

```
import module
module.stuff()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've clarified the question - I can't modify the imported module to have all the code in a stuff function like that.

Answer (score 1):

Code in a main stanza usually *never* makes sense to run directly. If you want to run it then use `subprocess` to run it in another Python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks.  In this occasion it does, and running it with subprocess doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a main module in Python:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os

def main(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print(arg1, arg2, arg3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(*sys.argv)
```

But you can also include

```
def main():
   #The module contains Python code specific to the library module, 
   #like tests, and follow the module with this:

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(*sys.argv)
```

in any module you would like to run as main.

For example, if you have a library module, you can always use this construct to execute something specific like tests.

Comment: Thanks, but I've clarified the question - I can't modify the imported module to have all the code in a main function like that.

Answer (score -1):

Put it in a function:

```
def _main():
   do stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've clarified the question - I can't modify the imported module to have all the code in a main function like that.