# Run a python file using another

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Note:-** Wait before you mark my question as duplicate please read it completely.

I wan't to `run` a python file using another.
I have tried using `runpy`,`os.system` & `subprocess`. The problem with `subprocess` and `os.system` command is that it fails for systems which have python2 and python3 both installed if i just run with `python`. If i run it with `python3` i fails for people having single installation.

The problem with `runpy` is that it does not work according to my needs.
The following is run my directory structure

```
test\
   average\
       average.py
       average_test.py
   many similar directories like average...
   run_tests.py
```

The content of average is

```
def average(...args):
     # Do something
```

The content of average_test.py

```
from average import average
def average_test():
    assert average(1,2,3) == 2
```

Now if i use `runpy.run_path` it throws a ImportError saying `average` is not a module. The `os.system` and `subprocess.call` works perfectly but I hope my "testing_framework" will be used by many so I can't use the above two functions. Isn't there any other way to do it. I have researched the whole of SO and google but didn't find a solutions.

Also `sys.path.append/insert` will not help as I can't tell my "users" to add this to every file of theirs.

Is there no easy way to do it? I mean like `pytest` accomplishes this so there must be a way.

Thank you moderators for reading my question.

**EDIT** I forgot to mention that I wan't the code to be run in `if __name__ == '__main__'` block too and I have also tried using a snippet from another SO answer which fails too. The snippet was

```
def exec_full(filepath):
    global_namespace = {
        "__file__": filepath,
        "__name__": "__main__",
    }
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
        exec(compile(file.read(), filepath, 'exec'), global_namespace)
```

Please note that the directory structure was just an example the user may have a different code/directory structure.

**NOTE:-** I found the answer. I needed to do `subprocess.call([sys.executable,file_path])`. `sys.executable` returns the path for the python executable file for the current version.

Comment: You could just import it? That runs a file...

Comment: I think i forgot to mention that the code in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` should be run too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160643/how-to-import-a-module-as-main take a look at this

Comment: I took and all answers suggest changing the code which you  already know from my question that I can't. The solution of @Unode might work but recommends not to use in production code. :(

Comment: If the code comes from a separate user, maybe just start it in a separate process using [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)?

Comment: @Kos I have python2 and python3 both installed. python runs python2 version and python3 runs python3 version and I believe there might many people like me. But there are people for whom python runs python3 and python3 gives error so I think there is no way to use subprocess.(I think i mentioned this in the answer)

Comment: Err... Python has no shortage of unittest frameworks, starting with the stdlib's `unittest`.  Do you really need a new testing framework ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yeah I know this is a stupid thing to do but I love doing stupid things :)

Comment: @RohitKumar well I wouldn't spoil your fun then !-)

Comment: @RohitKumar I thought systems with python 3 also have a `python3` and `python3.6` binaries available :( Which OS has missing `python3`? Maybe you could do a little discovery function that tries a few binaries using `subprocess` and picks the correct one.

Comment: @Kos I found the solution I will update the question.

Comment: If you run this script in a virtualenv, this will use the same python interpreter from the virtualenv to run the given script - is that what you want?

Comment: @Kos which why found this solution helpful because it works with the venv version

Answer (score 0):

```
    Create an empty __init__.py in average folder
    And then try to import

    from average import average 

    it would work like charm :)

    test\
       average\
           average.py
           average_test.py
           __init__.py
       many similar directories like average...
       run_tests.py
```