# Python interleave stdin/stdout of subprocess similar to terminal

Tags: python, subprocess, pytest

I'm writing an autograder for student assignments. Some of the assignments are to write programs that read from STDIN and print to STDOUT.

Currently, my grader passes the input in a single batch and then reads all the STDOUT as a single batch (impl: I use `subprocess.run(..., input="blue\n7\n".encode(), capture_output=True)`).

However, when providing feedback to students, it would be more helpful to interleave the STDOUT and STDIN, like they would experience if they were running their program from the terminal.

So, for a program that asks for a color and number, I currently can represent STDIN and STDOUT as:

**STDIN**

```
blue
7
```

**STDOUT**

```
name a color: pick a number: nice choices :)
```

But what I want to be able to show after the test runs is:

```
name a color: blue
pick a number: 7
nice choices :)
```

Is this a solved problem? If not, what existing tools can I put together to accomplish this? In 30 minutes of SO/google research, I see there are a lot of ways to approach subprocess communication, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the most fruitful direction.

Comment: There are 3rd-party tools that emulate a TTY and record timings. It's only "solved" if you use one of them.

Comment: _However_, note that even with a real TTY with local loopback enabled, when you type `blue` and `7` before the prompts for them are entered (say, by copy-and-pasting a text block that includes both responses into a program that's slower than the paste operation itself), they're shown on the display _before the prompts_; local echo is done _by the terminal_, so it looks at when the content is _typed_, not when it's _consumed_. You're "typing" it all up-front at the beginning, so software that records content being available before it's prompted for isn't going to create the sequence you want.

Comment: If you're directing your students to use specific calls, like `input()`, and you control the Python interpreter being used, you could certainly modify those calls to do _their own_ echo of results. (Note the existence of `site.py` and similar means to run arbitrary code before the script being invoked actually starts).

Answer (score 1):

The comments from Charles Duffy, together with information from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31395912/2288986) to another question let to my current solution.

Instead of running the student submission through `Popen` (or derivative), I call it programmatically with `runpy.run_path`:

```py
runpy.run_path(script_name, _globals, '__main__')
```

This allows me to run the script as if it were `__main__`, as if it were being run from the terminal.

I setup `_globals` with custom versions of `input` and `print` in order to intercept those calls and record the activity. Also, I overwrite `sys.argv` in `_globals` to have the simulated parameters for the submission.

By intercepting `input`, I can both assert that the correct prompt is printed as well as provide the appropriate response.

*Extra*: to simplify the testing, I wrote a class that loads an expected dialog, then runs the provided script and asserts that each `input` and `print` follows the expected dialog.

The final result can be found in [byu-pytest-utils/io_checker.py](https://github.com/BYU-CS110/byu_pytest_utils/blob/master/byu_pytest_utils/io_checker.py)